# Start up computer in the morning

Tags: windows, batch-file

We are requested by management to shutdown all systems when we leave in the afternoon, any system left on is consequently shutdown by the cleaner (pulls the powercord i guess).

What I hate though is that I have to wait for logon scripts regesters and updates and the likes in the morning.

Rather I would like to know if I can batch start (though any other program language will also do) my computer to start some 15mins before i arrive this way the system will have done all its doodaa and magic by the time i get there.

simular to when you switch of your mobile the alarm in the morning turns it back on, computer also has a clock right?

Comment: About the clock in the computer, Yes. The CMOS battery in computer helps the computer keep track of what time it is when the computer is not on. Normally it looks like a watch battery. I have had to replace one of those once in a Think-pad due to it dieing. When the CMOS battery dies, BIOS will prompt you for the time and date every time you start your computer.

Answer (score 7):

You can normally do that in the BIOS (press ESC/F1/DEL/whatever you need for your PC, look at what it says directly after pressing the power button to boot the PC), but normal Software doesn't have control over it.

Comment: The OS can set BIOS alarms.  In the Task Scheduler for Windows XP & newer, there's a checkbox to wake the computer to run a task.  I don't know how it works for other OSes though.  The OP would need to enable automatic logons though, I'm not sure how that would go over with IT.

Comment: Automated logons probably won't fly, but at least the scheduled power-on will help cut down some of the pre-logon processing time (OS load, other scripts) the user normally has to wait for.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to set up POE (Power Over Ethernet) for you computer (if it is support with your hardware). And set a task to run from your home computer (or any computer that is on at that time) everyday at a specific time that would turn your computer on. This will only work if your home computer is on at that time though.

EDIT: Yes I meant WOL. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Are you confusing POE with WOL (wake on LAN)? That would be likely be tricky to get through his company firewall.

Comment: Why -1 over me confusing the two acronyms? That is the way you could set it up though. He never said anything about going through a firewall, so how would that be a factor if I am unaware of one?

Comment: Okay +1 for correcting yourself =)

Comment: @David - He's trying to implement this for his work computer.  The firewall is a very logical and safe assumption.

Comment: @Iszi, You could always set WOL to use port 80.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished with a server that supports waking at a particular time and running a script as a scheduled task that pushes wake on lan packets.  I used this to power on PC's at 3AM and set automatic updates to try at 3:30 in a collegiate environment.